# UNION operation with the same table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, union-all

I have a scenario where I need to query data in a single row as multiple columns,

Table format is as follows,

SAMPLE_TABLE [ID, REF_TAB_A,REF_TAB_B,REF_TAB_C]

I need REF_TAB_A,REF_TAB_B,REF_TAB_C values in a single column. What I did is use UNION ALL as follows,

```
SELECT REF_TAB_A FROM SAMPLE_TABLE 
UNION ALL
SELECT REF_TAB_B FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT REF_TAB_C FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
```

Is there any other way to do this?? What is the most efficient way to handle such a scenario??

(I'm using oracle 11g)

Thanks in advance.. :D

Comment: Did you try it? seems to be working.

Comment: Yes, It's working fine, but I'm not sure whether this is the best way to do this...

Comment: But it 3 query against one query + client workaround. Is your DB highloaded?

Comment: Well I need this at the db side...

Answer (score 2):

Using `union all` generally results in three scans of the table.  An alternative approach is a little messier but should have just one scan:

```
SELECT (case when which = 'A' then REF_TAB_A
             when which = 'B' then REF_TAB_B
             when which = 'C' then REF_TAB_C
        end)
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE cross join
     (select 'A' as which from dual union all select 'B' from dual union all select 'C' from dual
     ) iter
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alias the columns:

```
SELECT REF_TAB_A tab FROM SAMPLE_TABLE 
UNION ALL
SELECT REF_TAB_B tab FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT REF_TAB_C tab FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
```

What you really need to do, however, is to normalize your database.  Whenever you have columns with repeating names like name1, name2, name3, namea, nameb, and namec, it is a sign that you want another table and a 1-many relationship between them.

```
CREATE TABLE tabs (
    tab_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    sample_table_id NUMBER,
    tab VARCHAR2(255),
    CONSTRAINT FK_sample_table
        FOREIGN KEY(sample_table_id)
        REFERENCES SAMPLE_TABLE(sample_table_id)
)
```

Now your query involves a simple `JOIN`.

```
SELECT
   tab
FROM tabs t
JOIN SAMPLE_TABLE st ON t.sample_table_id = st.sample_table_id
WHERE
    ...
```

Comment: actually all REF_TAB_A ,REF_TAB_B,REF_TAB_C refer to the same table. It is required that one record of SAMPLE_TABLE refer to 3 records in the other table

Comment: This would be like having a `PERSON` table and a `PHONE_NUMBER` table; the `PERSON` table could have a `cell_phone`, a `home_phone` and a `work_phone` column.  Still, having 3 columns make answering the question  "Who has phone number 703-555-1234?" difficult.  You have to go the `UNION` route.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Gordon's CROSS JOIN trick Oracle has the [UNPIVOT clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) in the SELECT statement specifically for this situation.

Assuming this table:

```
create table tmp_test ( a number, b number, c number );

insert all
 into tmp_test values (1,2,3)
 into tmp_test values (4,5,6)
select * from dual;
```

The following query would do what you require:

```
 select col
   from tmp_test
unpivot ( col for i in (a,b,c) );

       COL
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6

6 rows selected.
```

For this small example an explain plan indicates that using the inbuilt functionality would be more efficient but but test both options and see what's better.

Comment: Thanx Ben, I'll test the both adopt the best one :D